# What database does StackOverflow use?

Tags: support, architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What was Stack Overflow built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)

I just wanted to know what database StackOverflow uses. The site seems pretty active and very responsive.

Comment: should be on meta!

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with

Answer (score 11):

There's a decent write up at: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Answer (score 9):

Sql server 2008