# Issue with the new duplicate question link

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

Have a look at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166756/187824). This question is closed as duplicate and the notice is displayed as:

> **This question already has an answer here:**
>   What database does StackOverflow use? [duplicate] *2 answers*
>   Retag without privilege *1 answer*

But actually, that question is not a duplicate of the question [What database does StackOverflow use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17988). It was marked as a duplicate by [Diago mistakenly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166756/retag-question-reputation-required-500#comment-488499). So now it is linking us to a wrong duplicate question. In the previous method (*possible duplicate*) we were able to edit duplicate link and remove wrong duplicate link but now we are not able to edit duplicate link. So what can we do in this situation?

I don't know whether moderators are able to remove it or not. If they are able to remove it then flagging the question will solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The proposed solution was that **[privileged users will be able to disagree with a proposed duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138316/improve-ui-flow-for-close-as-duplicate)**.

Doing so will solve this (and a whole bunch of other problems as well).

Comment: Great. But the issue remains until that feature is implemented.

Comment: @hims056: Indeed. But I'm having a good feeling about this one :)