# Feeds do not contain new-style duplicate links

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, markdown, feed

I see that duplicate links are no longer part of the question text. I think this is a fine change (especially that they are no longer marked up as `blockquote`s), other than [ensuring there are sufficient management tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166770/issue-with-the-new-duplicate-question-link), but one side effect I have observed is that feeds, e.g. [the main feed for Meta, which I'm sure will contain many example duplicates at any hour of the day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds), no longer contain links to the duplicate-of question(s). Perhaps this could be re-added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those blocks will be added back in the next build.